# Retrieve a post by id with RestFB API

Tags: java, facebook, api, post, restfb

I'm using http://restfb.com/

I have the id of a post and i want to retrieve it, but i can't find how! I search on the documentation of the website and also on google but seems that no one has this problem.

I tried with:

```
facebookClient.fetchObject(id, JsonObject.class);
```

but i get this error:

```
Can't retrive post: Received Facebook error response of type GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request.
```

Comment: What code is returned in the response JSON?

Comment: I don't know, here my block of code:
`try{
    return facebookClient.fetchObject(id, JsonObject.class);
} catch (FacebookException e) {
    System.err.println("Can't retrive post: " + e.getMessage());
    return null;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Post post = client.fetchObject(id, Post.class, Parameter.with("fields", "from,to,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)"));
```